# SSRS 2008 R2, VS 2008, User Defined Table Types

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a stored proc that I use to create some customized lists.  I'm trying to create it as an SSRS report, but it's running into a sticking point where it chokes trying to deal with the User Defined Table Type parameters.

Am I just screwed?

As an aside, it does work when you call it with a sql exec statement.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you trying to use UDT as a parameter?

Comment: At this point, sort of because I can. I'm passing arrays into the sproc and since I have SQL 2008 R2, I'd rather use UDT's instead of csv, etc

Comment: Can you clarify? What does "I have a stored proc that I use to create some customized lists. I'm trying to create it as an SSRS report" mean? You're trying to create a stored proc as part of your report? Or do you mean that you'd like to call the SP from your report?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is currently no "native" way to pass table-valued parameters from SSRS to a stored procedure. However it is still can be done in a sort of a hackish way:[Using Table-Valued Parameters With SQL Server Reporting Services](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2012/06/21/using-table-valued-parameters-with-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx) or [Passing Multivalued Parameters in SQL Server 2008](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/business-intelligence/passing-multivalued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008).